# How should I change the Time to Live property for a Hazelcast Cluster?

Tags: rest, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Hazelcast Configuration modifies the map configuration value for the "Time to Live" or "TTL" property at runtime either through the Hazelcast client or a RESTful API call.

I saw the Hazelcast Mancenter through which we can modify the Map TTL value at runtime without bringing the cluster down.

Is there a way to change the TTL value from the Hazelcast client program or RESTful API call?

Note: I do not want to add one more node to the cluster just to change the TTL value.  I am also not interested in bringing the cluster down change the XML configuration and restart the Hazelcast cluster.

Comment: There's no such a call/api at the moment. Even Hazelcast Management Center method is not complete, IMap config updates are not propagated to the newly joined nodes.

Comment: Modified wording and grammar to be clearer and easier to read.  Modified title to clearly communicate the intent of the question.  The question is a good one - just remember to use good English grammar and syntax - acronyms like 'TTL' and 'XML' are always represented in capital letters.  Effective question titles are usually brief, and expanded upon in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an overridden `IMap.put(K key, V value, long ttl, TimeUnit ttlUnit)` call to specify the desired timeout value. With this, you can have `ttl` & `ttlUnit` field value changing dynamically based on your requirements.

If you want to apply a new TTL value for existing entries, you can iterate over the entries and reset TTL - [refer this javadoc](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#set%28K,%20V,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). This is not an optimal solution, but this is the best solution as of now. A Github ticket is already raised for this feature with Hazelcast team, you can track it here: [Improve map re-config capabilities](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/14750)